# How to show JavaScript errors using JSHint?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I am trying to build a simple JavaScript validator, something like [JSHint](http://jshint.com). I want to write a JavaScript code and click a "Validate" button, and the errors should show up.

Passing the JavaScript source like this JSHINT(js-source) just gives you "true" or "false" depending on whether the code is valid or not. I would like to get the details (e.g. line number where the error ocurred, error type etc.) of each error.

Here's what I already have.

http://jsbin.com/AZEpOHi/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/):

> If your input passes JSHint tests, the function will return true. Otherwise, it will return false. In that case, you can use JSHINT.errors to retrieve the errors or request a complete report by calling the JSHINT.data() method.

The errors are in the `JSHINT.errors` array, and those objects include line numbers and error reasons.

Here's [a jsfiddle that demonstrates a simple use of JSHINT.errors](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/BLwPr/).

Comment: I understand. Would you be able to provide an example? May be a link?

Comment: This info has vanished from the documentation page and [can't even be found in the history of the page](https://github.com/jshint/jshint.github.io/commits/dev/pages/docs.md). A [clone of the old documentation from 2013](https://github.com/jshint/jshint.github.io/blob/dev/pages/docs.md) is available, but the fact that this was removed from the up-to-date documentation makes me wonder whether JSHint is still meant to be used like that.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle to use the latest jshint and it still works as expected. It is indeed strange that all docs related to the node-style use seem to be gone. If you [look at the source](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/cli.js#L487-L500), this is how jshint itself prints linting information when it is run from the command-line. I am unsure whether it is safe to assume that it will stay this way.